# C++: Pointers to union-members considered distinct?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This toy code:

```cpp
union a { 
  int b; 
  int c; 
};

template<int a::* p> void b() {}
template<> void b< &a::b >()  {}
template<> void b< &a::c >()  {}
```

Builds fine in clang and gcc, but in MSVC gives:

> error C2766: explicit specialization; 'void b<pointer-to-member(0x0)>(void)' has already been defined

Compiler-explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/TfoMjv8ch

As can be seen in CE, in gcc/clang the specialization names mangling encodes the union-member names:

```
_Z1bIXadL_ZN1a1bEEEEvv
               ^
_Z1bIXadL_ZN1a1cEEEEvv
               ^
```

but in MSVC the mangling encodes just the member offset within the union (0), and therefore the specializations are considered duplicate:

```
??$b@$0A@@@YAXXZ
      ^
```

Is this an MSVC bug or undefined/unspecified behavior?  Any pointers (hehe) to relevant standard clauses?

Comment: There should be no reason to use untagged unions in C++. You're just setting yourself up for undefined behavior! Pointers to members on a union could point to non-active members for example. TLDR do NOT use unions in C++ if you need something like a union in C++ use std::variant.

Comment: @PepijnKramer  https://twitter.com/eloffd/status/1743353682022838377?s=20

Comment: I am not trying to confuse you. It is not even about recommended practice, it is about C++ really behaving differently than "C".  Really read the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior. So even if it would compile... I would not dare to write code depending on pointers to members of unions.

Comment: @PepijnKramer the comic is about the common SO practice of not answering the actual question.

Comment: Oh that, but that is because there might be a problem even more fundamental than the question asked. It also not necessarily a comment to you (who might understand the undefined behavior). There are also other people reading these comments that may learn something from them. Note that I never posted this as an answer (because I know it is not) but as a commment... because it is just that : a comment :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clang and GCC are correct. We have this for determining the identity of specializations:

> **[temp.type]**
>
> 1 Two template-ids are the same if
>
> - ...
> - the template parameter values determined by their corresponding non-type template arguments ([temp.arg.nontype]) are
>   *template-argument-equivalent* (see below), and
> - ...
>
> Two template-ids that are the same refer to the same class, function,
> or variable.
>
> [2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type#2.6) Two values are template-argument-equivalent if they are of the
> same type and
>
> - ...
> - they are of pointer-to-member type and they refer to the same class member or are both the null member pointer value, or
> - ...

[Since a union is a class defined by special key](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general-1), this applies, and the two specializations are distinct on account of the two pointers being to different members.

Yes, those are indeed different members. They may have the same type, but only one can be active at a time, regardless. Furthermore, the standard acknowledges they are still different when saying their pointers must compare equal:

> **[expr.eq]**
>
> [4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#4.5) Comparing pointers to members is defined as follows:
>
> - ...
> - If both refer to (possibly different) members of the same union, they compare equal.
> - ...

This probably accounts for the oversight in MSVC, where the value of the pointers is the only thing that's encoded in the mangling.